# Calling API in Background when App is Killed in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to implement a feature in my app where I call an API in the background even when the app is in a killed state.

I've done some research and found that libraries like HeadlessJS and React Native Job Scheduler might help achieve this but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I've tried using HeadlessJS to handle the background task execution, but I'm not sure how to make it work when the app is killed.

```js
// In my App.js
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('MyTask', () => require('./MyTask'));

// In MyTask.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('MyTask', () => {
  // Call API here
  // This also works in the foreground or background, but not when the app is killed.
});
```

I've read the documentation for both libraries but I can't find a clear example of how to call an API in the background when the app is killed. Can someone please provide a step-by-step guide or point out what I might be missing in my implementation?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot call an API if your app has been killed.

Comment: i want to update user location to server when my app is in background or kill state